# SQL Server database design for mvc application

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement where I want to store 5 years amounts divided by months and quarters in database. Its not necessary that all amounts will be filled in for example user can input data for 3 months for 1st year and also can provide amount for all the months in another year.

I came up with following design

1. `Fields` = this table is used for saving month names and associated quarter information. data would like as below

   ```
   FieldId        FieldName         Quarter
      1             Jan               q1
      2             Feb               q1
      3             march             q1
      4             q1total           q1
   ```
2. Data

   ```
   DataId         FieldId           Amount   year
      1             1                100    2015
      2             2                200    2015
      3             3                300    2015
      4             4                600    2016
   ```

With this approach for every budget information I have to save almost 80 records (5 years data for each month and quarter) in database in worse case.

I would like to know more efficient way to design tables for this requirement.

Comment: What does your question have to do with MVC?

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to store month name or what quarter it's in -- that can be calculated on the fly by date functions of your database or programming language. I'd get rid of the `Fields` table completely, drop the `year` and `FieldId` fields from the `Data` table, and then add a basic date field to the `Data` table. All you need is this:

```
ID Date       Amount
-- ---------- ------
 1 2015-01-01    100
 2 2015-02-01    200
```

Then you just add a date span for your where clause. If you want Jan:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE date >= '2015-01-01' AND date < '2015-02-01';
```

If you want Q1:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE date >= '2015-01-01' AND date < '2015-04-01';
```

Or (in MySQL, for example):

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE YEAR(date) = 2015 AND QUATER(date) = 1; -- Q1 2015
SELECT * FROM data WHERE YEAR(date) = 2015 AND MONTH(date) = 1;  -- Jan 2015
```

Note, I'm guessing you're probably tracking more than one budget. Perhaps one per user or one per department or something. In this case, you'll want an additional field to indicate who or what the record belongs to:

```
ID UserId Date       Amount
-- ------ ---------- ------
 1      1 2015-01-01    100
 2      1 2015-02-01    200
```

Or:

```
ID DepartmentId Date       Amount
-- ------------ ---------- ------
 1            1 2015-01-01    100
 2            1 2015-02-01    200
```

Comment: This design is much better and as far as I can tell fill all of the OP's original requirements.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your reply! you are right..fields table would not be required. But another question is if we want to save 5 years data by month for one budget input record then there would 60-90 associated rows in database. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: There would be one row for each month that has a value. If every single month has a value, then you'd have a maximum of 60 rows for your five-year period. Don't store the quarterly values, it's redundant. You can just issue a query with SUM() to get the quarterly values.

Comment: This model allows multiple values within a single month which sounds like it's a violation of the problem definition.  Rather than the `Date` field two fields `Year` and `Month` would provide the same functionality but allow the database to enforce the requirement that each month is stored only 0 or 1 times.

Comment: If you split the date into year and month then you lose date validation and the ability to use builtin date functions. If only one date is allowed per month, I'd do it by putting a unique index on stamp and a constraint check like DAY(date) = 1.

Comment: I really like the approach of using date column but requirements are little different for me.

Comment: Quarters start from july and sometimes user would provide quarter totals and not monthly values and quarterly totals should not be equally divided among all the months.

Comment: "Quarters start from july..." That's fine, you can still use the QUARTER() function, just specify 3 (instead of 1) when you want the "1st" quarter.

Comment: "sometimes user would provide quarter totals and not monthly values" Hmm, well, it would be pretty simple to add another field `type` that indicates whether the record is monthly or quarterly, and then the `stamp` field would just indicate the start of the month or the start of the quarter. It would be tricky though to ensure that you don't have any monthly records inside the same range as a quarterly. You'd likely have to write your own constraint check function, or perform the required checks in your app before inserting a new row.

Answer (score 0):

> With this approach for every budget information I have to save almost 80 records (5 years data for each month and quarter) in database in worse case

To be honest - 80, 800 or 8000 records, it doesn't matter much. With that amount of data you don't need to worry about "efficiency", but rather about *maintenance* and *future growth*.

You'll want to design it so that it is easy to maintain and easy to change (because it will change). Storing quaters, years and months now might make sense if you want to shave off a nano-second in query time, or want to have an easier query to retrieve the data. But in 1 year, when someone will ask you also get weekly statistics, this design will fail you.

I agree with Alex answer about the design of that particular table. If you store a date you have freedom to use it as you please. But my answer is more of a  general note for any table you will create:

Don't get stuck in how to optimize it **now**, instead try to think ahead and store data with as much detail as possible (unless building a huge database).